# How does clang check redefinitions?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-tidy

I'm new to Clang, and trying to write some clang-tidy checks. I want to find something that works as a **"variable table"**, to check if some names are well-formed.

My intuition is like this:

To write redefinition code will sometimes cause an error, which is thrown out by Clang's diagnostics. like:

```cpp
int main(){
int x;
int x; // error: redefinition
return 0;
}
```

From my perspective, clang may keep a dynamic variable table to check whether a new definition is compatible/overloading/error.

I tried to dive into clang source code and explored something:

- `Identifiertable`, is kept by preprocessor, which marks all the identifiers, but does not do  the semantic legal checking.
- `DeclContext`, which seems to be an interface for users to use, a product produced by semantic checking.

My question is :

- How Clang do the legal checking?
- Am I able to get the variable table(If there exists such kind of things)?
- If I cannot get such things, how could I know which variables are reachable from a location?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; see **Answers** below.

---

### Discussion

All of your questions are related to one term of C standard, *identifier*, in C99-6.2.1-p1:

> An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or
> enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter.

Each identifier has its own *scope*, one of the following, according to C99-6.2.1-p2:

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be
> used) only within a region of program text called its scope.

Since what you are interested in are the variables inside a function (i.e., `int x`), then it should then obtain a *block scope*.

There is an process called *linkage* for the *identifiers* in the same *scope*, according to C99-6.2.2-p2:

> An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be
> made to refer to the same object or function by a process called linkage.

This is exactly the one that put a constraint that there should be only one *identifier* for one same *object*, or in your saying, definition ***legally checking***. Therefore compiling the following codes

```c
/* file_1.c */
int a = 123;

/* file_2.c */
int a = 456;
```

would cause an **linkage error**:

```
% clang file_*
...
ld: 1 duplicate symbol
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

**However**, in your case, the *identifiers* are inside the same function body, which is more likely the following:

```c
/* file.c */
int main(){
  int b;
  int b=1;
}
```

Here *identifier* `b` has a *block scope*, which shall have **no linkage**, according to C99-6.2.2-p6:

> The following identifiers have **no linkage**: an identifier declared to be anything other than
> an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope
> identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

Having no linkage means that we cannot apply the rules mentioned above to it, that is, it should not be related to a linkage error kind.

It is naturally considered it as an error of redefinition. But, while it is indeed defined in C++, which is called [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), it is **NOT** in C.(check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986335/does-c-have-one-definition-rule-like-c) for more details)  There is no exact definition for dealing with those duplicate identifiers in a same block scope. Hence it is an **implementation-defined** behavior. This might be the reason why with *clang*, the resulting errors after compiling the above codes (file.c) differs from the ones by *gcc*, as shown below:
*(note that the term 'with no linkage' by gcc)*

```
# ---
# GCC (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04))
# ---
$ gcc file.c 
file.c: In function ‘main’:
file.c:4:6: error: redeclaration of ‘b’ with no linkage
  int b=1;
      ^
file.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘b’ was here
  int b;
      ^


# ---
# CLANG  (Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3))
# ---
% clang file.c 
file.c:4:6: error: redefinition of 'b'
 int b;
     ^
file.c:3:6: note: previous definition is here
 int b=1;
     ^
1 error generated.
```

---

### Answers

With all things above, I think it suffices to answer your questions:

> How clang perform the definition legally checking?

For global variables, either *clang* or *gcc* would follow the C standard rules, that is to say, they handle the so-called "redefinition errors" by the process called *Linkage*. For local variables, it is undefined behavior, or more precisely, **implementation-defined** behavior.

In fact, They both view the "redefinition" as an error. Although variable names inside a function body would be vanished after compiled (you can verify this in the assembly output), it is undoubtedly more natural and helpful for letting them be unique.

> Am I able to get the variable table(If there exists such kind of things)?

Having not so much knowledge about *clang* internals, but according to the standards quoted above, along with [an analysis of compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181369/17416117), we can infer that [IdentifierTable](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Basic/IdentifierTable.h) might not much fit your needs, since it exists in "preprocessing" stage, which is before "linking" stage. To take a look how *clang* compiler deals with duplicate variables (or more formally, symbols), and how to store them, you might want to check the whole project of [lld](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lld), or in particular, [SymbolTable](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lld/ELF/SymbolTable.h#L22).

Comment: Thanks much for your patient answer! It helps me with my confusion and point out a clear direction to do more try. Thanks again!